# how to fetch data from API and set to the Image

Tags: api, swiftui, viewmodel

> This is my Model And I want to fetch data of publisherBanner and set
> to the View But I can not set the image in view

```
    import Foundation


public struct Banner: Decodable {
    public let publisherBanners: [PublisherBanner]

    public init(publisherBanners: [PublisherBanner]) {
        self.publisherBanners = publisherBanners
    }
}

    
    public struct PublisherBanner: Decodable, Hashable {
        public var id = UUID()
    //    public let bannerFor: String
    //    public let imageName: String
        public let url: String
    
        public init(url: String) {
            
    
            self.url = url
        }
    }
```

> This is my ViewModel

```
class BannerVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datas = [PublisherBanner]()
    let url = "apiUrlExample"
    
    init() {
        getData(url: url)
    }
    
    
    func getData(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Banner.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.datas = results.publisherBanners
                      
                      
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

> And this is My View where I want to set Image

```
struct BannerView: View {
@StateObject var bannerObject = BannerVM()
var body: some View{
    ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
        HStack(spacing:15) {
            ForEach(bannerObject.datas, id: \.id){ item in
                
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(item.url)")) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable().padding(4)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 215)
                } placeholder: {
                    Image("logo_gray").resizable().padding(1)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 215)
                }
                  
                   
            }
        }
   


    }
    .padding(8)
    
}
```

}

> please help me for fetch the Image of My API

> I am trying to fetch but i failed many times and please help me. And
> thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to the solution. It confuses other readers. And you forgot to change `url` from `String` to `URL` so your code still doesn't work.

Comment: sorry for editing my code. And i rewrite the code. and thank you sir for resolve my Problem and now my code properly run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message you get

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "publisherBanners", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

It says that the value for key `id` in `PublisherBanner` is an `Int`, you have to declare

```
public struct PublisherBanner: Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable  {
    public let id: Int
    public let url: URL
}
```

By the way you can decode the url directly to `URL` and the `init` method is for free.

And as `PublisherBanner` already conforms to `Identifiable`  the code to load the image can be shortened to

```
ForEach(bannerObject.datas) { item in
    AsyncImage(url: item.url) { image in
```

Another *by the way* is that String Interpolation in `URL(string: "\(url)")` is redundant because `url` is already a `String`. This is sufficient: `URL(string: url)`